# main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file

Tags: magento2, php

I've spent all day trying to debug this.

system.log error stack:

```
[2016-11-16 16:37:18] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_2999a55d7d9f00b9a016b5e16762ce70a and handles default, customer_account_login: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:19] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_20a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles 1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:19] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:19] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:19] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:19] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_26f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:20] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'google/‌​button.phtml' in module: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect' block's name: 'inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button' [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:20] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'facebook/‌​button.phtml' in module: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect' block's name: 'inchoo_socialconnect_login_facebook_button' [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:20] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'twitter/‌​button.phtml' in module: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect' block's name: 'inchoo_socialconnect_login_twitter_button' [] []
[2016-11-16 16:37:20] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'pixelpin/‌​button.phtml' in module: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect' block's name: 'inchoo_socialconnect_login_pixelpin_button' [] []
```

snippet of customer_account_login.xml:

```
<body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.login.container">
        <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::login.phtml">
            <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Google\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::google/‌​button.phtml"/>
            <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Facebook\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_facebook_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::facebook/‌​button.phtml"/>
            <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Twitter\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_twitter_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::twitter/‌​button.phtml"/>
            <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_pixelpin_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::pixelpin/‌​button.phtml"/>
        </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

pixelpin/button.phtml:

```
<div class="clearer">
    <div class="inchoo-socialconnect-pixelpin">
        <div class="inchoo-socialconnect-pixelpin-left">

        </div>
        <div class="inchoo-socialconnect-pixelpin-inner">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->_getButtonUrl()); ?>"><?php echo $this->_getButtonText(); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="inchoo-socialconnect-pixelpin-right">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

snippet of login.phtml where pixelpin/button.phtml gets called:

```
<?php if($this->_pixelpinEnabled()): ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $this->_getButtCol(); ?> inchoo-socialconnect-login-lower-pixelpin">
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_login_pixelpin_button'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

file structure:

[image]

if you need any more information just ask

Answer (score 1):

For some reason. Magento 2 doesn't like button.phtml being in a custom folder (Inchoo_SocialConnect::**google**/‌​button.phtml), so i moved it to the root of the templates folder along side login.phtml (Inchoo_SocialConnect::login.phtml) so the template file path for button.phtml is now:

```
Inchoo_SocialConnect::button.phtml
```

I called it like this:

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_login_button'); ?>
```

and my layout file is as follows:

```
<body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.login.container">
        <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::login.phtml" cacheable="false"/>          
        <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::button.phtml" cacheable="false"/>     
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```